# Reading data from a Snapchat snapcode

Tags: image-processing, snapchat, scannable-code

I'm trying to read snapcode without the snapchat app and can read the information contained, someone has some information about how it works?

Thanks

Comment: did you had any luck?

Comment: No, no luck....